# How do you make a Wordpress plugin have "per post" options?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a Wordpress blog that requires a custom slideshow system with an admin panel on each post admin page (sort of like how Yoast's SEO plugin has options on each page).

How would I make the admin options appear on the post admin page?

Thanks,

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing much detail about your project but you probably [want to make some meta_boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) and save the data to as [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Here is a truncated example [culled from something I put together for a question at wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/72427/adding-an-assisting-editor-box-to-post-page). The details of some of the functions are not important for your question here but it illustrates the general 'how'. Follow the link for working but sincerely beta code.

```
// author checkboxes
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'assisting_editor' );
function assisting_editor() {
    add_meta_box(
        'assisting_editor', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Editorial Tasks' ), // meta box title
        'editor_tasks', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. This adds to posts only
        'side', // context, where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context
    );
}

// this is the callback that creates the meta box content
function editor_tasks( $post ) {
  // function details skipped; follow the link
}

// to save the data
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');
// callback for the save hook ^^
function save_metadata($postid) {
  // function details skipped; follow the link
}
```